# SYMFONY 5 - I try to put HTML code in mysql and it's not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony5

So I'm working on a project where I have a database that i've created with Symfony 5 and i'm using easyAdmin as a back-of

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $description;
```

I try to put html code like : `<p>Test</p>` but the website display me : `<p>Test</p>` and not just Test. Is it because it's a string ? How to I manage to display just Test ?

Thanks

Comment: How is it being displayed? It's probably escaped somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw` in twig template

```
{{ description|raw }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I use it in the Twig file or PHP file ?

Comment: In twig use it like: {{ description|raw }}

Comment: I'm using easy admin 3 so i don't have easy_admin.yaml but it works in the twig file ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Mark it as answer for others help.